# What are the rage of operating Temps, Crankcase and Alternator, of a 9500w Portable Generator

Tags: generator

I have purchased a Westinghouse WGen9500DFc generator. My Home Owners Association is requiring me to have a temperature cut-off added to the generator to minimize the risk of generator over heating and starting a fire. I did a lot of digging and I have a solution. In order to implement the solution I need to source temperature sensors. I need to get the maximum operating temperature range of the crankcase and alternator. I have contacted Westinghouse and they say that they do not have those details; when I know they do as they are parameters for quality testing.

So can anyone give me a feeling for the crankcase and alternator temperature range? At least it would be a starting point for me to test.

Thanks for the help in advance.
Scott

Comment: Crankcase you want ~below 400F(flash point of oil a bit higher).  The generator/alternator below 300F.  For a HOA I would get one set to 451F(do your reading).

Comment: @crip659 451 is perfect! But really, why in the !@#)$@#$)%^@) does an HOA need to get into such details. All they should care is (a) that all generators are installed and used in accordance with directions - e.g., if it says "20 feet away from any door or openable window" then they could cite you for that due to the risk (which is very real) of CO poisoning. Other than that, the **only** thing I think they have a right to get involved in is **noise**. Some generators are a lot louder than others, and noise complaints can be a real issue. Though TBH, if the utility power is out and

Comment: then I think offering the Officers of the HOA to let them store their food in your spare refrigerator that is running on your generator might well solve the problem. Just saying.

Comment: Agree w comments above, but couldn’t you just run it for a bit and then measure?

Comment: Thanks folks. I really appreciate the feedback. Regarding the HOA .... You are correct that they should not have a say regarding safety and its not in their charter ... But I have to live here, so I will do my best to alleviate concern. Thanks for helping me make that possible. Off I go.